# Problem with Flash and HTML Menu

Tags: css, flash, wordpress, wmode

I have a problem with a Flash object and the menu of my page.

The site is on Wordpress : http://www.pymedia.cl/st/

When I try to access to the menu, the menu content appears behind the Flash.  How can I fix this?

this is my code of the template section:

```
<div id="blog_posts" class="contentcontainer fix">
    <?php if(is_home()):?>
    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10.0.0.0" width="100" height="330">
        <param name="movie" value="http://pymedia.cl/st/flash/principal.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <embed src="http://pymedia.cl/st/flash/principal.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="330" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></embed>
    </object>
    <?php endif;?>
    <div class="texture fix">
        <?php include (ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/logo-slideshow/logo-slider.php'); ?>
        <div class="content fix <?php if(pagelines('leftsidebar')):?>leftsidebar<?php endif;?>">
            <div id="maincontent">
                <?php include (THEME_LIB . '/_principal.php'); ?> 
            </div>
            <?php get_sidebar();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `wmode` of the Flash to `transparent`. If you are using SWFObject to embed your Flash content, it's as simple as adding:

`yourObject.addParam('wmode', 'transparent','true');`

Alternatively, you can add a  `param` tag to the `object` tag: `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` and add a `wmode` parameter to the `object` tag: `wmode="transparent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Flash Satay](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed/) method and then add a param of:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```